# What is typeof(NaN) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I just happen to stumble upon a code which checks the `typeof` of a varable passed to it just like this.

```
function myNaN(b){

  if(typeof(b) == 'number'){
    // execute some code
  }

}
```

Whenever I call this function it works fine and passes the if condition if number is being passed.

However when I pass a `NaN` (which is the output of some other function) to this function the `if` condition returns true.

My question is it correct that `typeof(NaN) == 'number'` ? If so, why? Isn't it confusing?

Just try running `console.log(typeof(NaN));` in browser console to see what I mean.

Comment: `Number.isNaN(Number.NaN) === true`. `NaN` is of type `Number`, if you want to know whether it is a `number` or `NaN`, use `isNaN`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `typeof(NaN)` is number. You can check if the value is `NaN` specifically using the function `isNaN`.

Comment: NaN is a shorthand for "Not a Number" and you get NaN when trying to parse(Int/Float) a string that is not a number.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the: "isNan("1234")" function ? 
Here is some link if it helps: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp

Comment: `isNaN()` attempts to coerce to a number, so you can get some confusing results, like these. `isNaN(null); // false` `isNaN("   "); // false`